# Box-shadow trimmed in CSS columns in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css

I want the block elements inside CSS columns to have **box shadow**. The following, simplified code renders as expected in IE10 and Firefox 21, but in current Chrome version (28.0.1500.72) **shadows near the column sides are trimmed**.

The images present results in IE/FF (on the left), and Chrome on the right:

[image: Code rendered in IE/Firefox]
[image: Code rendered in Chrome]

(there's also some vertical shift, but it's not an issue)

Here's the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/buli_pl/KxYRc/1/

```css
div#column-container {
  /* Set 2 columns*/
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}
div#column-container div {
  background-color: yellow;
  /* set shadow for yellow elements */
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #000;
  /* Make sure that yellow div is not split between columns */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  /* the rest - just to better present the problem */
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="column-container">
  <div>box 1</div>
  <div>box 2</div>
  <div>box 3</div>
  <div>box 4</div>
  <div>box 5</div>
  <div>box 6</div>
</div>
```

Am I misusing some of those properties, or this is a Chrome issue? How can it be fixed at the moment?

Comment: I had the same problem when the outer `<div>` is added with property `overflow:hidden`. Try adding margin to the inner `<div>`s

Comment: it works this way indeed, but my columns are a part of a bigger layout and I need inner boxes exactly aligned to the column sides - that's why I would love to see some other way :)

Comment: Better you can go with the float: left as @Ajoshi said in his answer. It would be better.

Comment: The float approach is not equivalent. It might look so with the similar yellow boxes, but they are filling new rows, not columns

Comment: Looking for a solution right now, I see that `overflow:visible` (parent containing auto columns) does nothing, and neither does `display:inline-block` or `float:left` on the child divs (on the boxes casting shadows). I am having the same problem. Firefox is the ONLY browser out of Chrome, IE, Safari, & Opera to properly render columns containing boxes. I used `inline-block` to prevent mid-element column breaks, but that causes ANOTHER problem in non-FF browsers: extra tall column container. -_-

Comment: @buli, do you need to use the `column-count?` What's wrong with `float`?

Comment: I might work using calc() to reduce width of blocks to let shadows being seen  and rework margin and padding for nicer layout: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fiHCv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [flexbox](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/) for this instead of css columns.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/KxYRc/10/)**

**NB:** This currently doesn't work in Firefox because it still doesn't support the `flex-wrap` property, however according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) - this will be supported in version 28

### CSS

```
div#column-container {   
    height: 270px; /* NB: IE requires the height property. max-height won't work on IE)*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
}
```

### **EDIT**: ([Updated FIDDLE which includes support for Firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/KxYRc/19/))

As per @buli's suggestion to temporarily use the -moz-colums-count for Firefox as long as flex-wrap is not supported:

Well, you could do this with the @supports which allows us to perform  feature queries - sort of like Modernizr, but with CSS.

The good thing here, is that [Firefox supports them](http://caniuse.com/css-featurequeries).

So if I add the following code: (updated as per Pavlo's suggestion)

```
@supports (not (flex-wrap: wrap)) and (-moz-columns: 2) {
    div#column-container { 
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
        display: block;
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Now, Firefox will use CSS columns, whereas other browsers will use flexbox.

Comment: nice idea, and this seem to solve the problem for me in Chrome (and I think I can use the -moz-colums-count for Firefox as long as flex-wrap is not supported).

Comment: @buli - I took up your suggestion to include Firefox support

Comment: Why not check support for `exactly` what we want? `@supports (not (flex-wrap: wrap)) and (-moz-columns: 2) {}`: http://jsfiddle.net/c4Cez/

Comment: Additionally, this solution won't work for Safari 6.

Comment: @Pavlo, ok fair enough. I updated the post with your version of supports. But why do you say that this won't work for Safari 6.0? Accoording to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) - Safiri 6.0 supports flexbox (with -webkit prefix)

Comment: It supports the old, 2009 flexbox and not wrapping, I believe.

Answer (score 48):

Just happened upon a potentially more straightforward solution that seems to work. Applying transform: translateZ(0); to the elements with box-shadows seems to be resolving this issue. In the supplied code, you would add this to your *div#column-container div* rule.

```
.container{
  break-inside: avoid;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 2rem;
}
.box{
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  break-inside: avoid;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

https://codepen.io/MarkitDigital/pen/RdLoRG

Comment: +1 Only solution that also works when i need a container with dynamic height, which sorts the children in columns (Masonry layout style) and uses the available horizontal space for the children (aka minimal height, maximal width).

Comment: Good find!  I’d suggest using a vendor prefix, i.e. `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` so as not to impact any rendering optimizations in other browsers, as the issue is clearly WebKit-specific (there’s no issue in Firefox or IE/Edge).  In my case, it prevents a sliver of the shadow appearing at the bottom of the previous column, though I’m finding it still clipped at the top of subsequent columns whereas it’s not clipped at the top of the first column (but I think Chrome users will have to live with that).

Comment: This should be the chosen answer, since the question was about css columns and not flex! I'd never figure this one out by myself... kudos to you.

Comment: This works a treat in Chrome but unfortunately in Safari (v13.1) entire boxes disappear

Comment: Only solution that works.
Stack Overflow moderators, you guys really need to point to which solution works when we provide code snippets when we try to post similar questions. You're not being helpful when you just close posts. Here's my post that was closed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68406300/css-column-layout-cutting-off-box-shadow-clipping-elements. Be more constructive and less destructive.

Comment: hero!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

this should work too : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fiHCv

(from my comment to get your feeling about it :) )

It might work using calc() to reduce width of blocks to let shadows being seen and rework margin and padding for nicer layout

```
div#column-container {   
    /* Set 2 columns*/
    column-count: 2;
  column-gap:0;
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  padding:20px 0;
}

div#column-container div {
    background-color: yellow;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #000; 

    /* Make sure that yellow div is not split between columns */
    display: inline-block;
  /* leave room for shadow to be drawn */
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    /* the rest - just to better present the problem */
    height: 70px;
    margin: 20px;    
}
```

manage margin and padding, so top of columns may be on same vertical level and fit to your grid

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple work-around for Chrome: For your yellow blocks, just change the width and the margin. For the drop-shadow to show up you want to make sure there is some margin room around the block.

```
width: 80%;
margin: 1em 10%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dPg2n/1/ --- Works in both Chrome 31 and FireFox 10.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome is failing to compensate for the extra width added by the shadow.

If you add "text-align: center;" to the div#column-container, the yellow inner div will center and you can now see shadow on the left edge.

If change the insignificant "width: 100%;" on the yellow inner div to "width: 85%;" (or a width of your choice) now there is room for the entire shadow.

```
div#column-container {   
  /* Set 2 columns*/
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;

   /* insignificant - except text-align, which corrects Chrome */
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

div#column-container div {
  background-color: yellow;

  /* set shadow for yellow elements */
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 15px #000;
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 15px #000; 

  /* Make sure that yellow div is not split between columns */
  display: inline-block;

  /* the rest - width was significant for Chrome, you may need to adjust for your real project */
  width: 85%;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;    
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/k24NH/)

Answer (score 1):

I think column-count is conflicting with chrome...

Try This:

```
div#column-container {
  /* Set 2 columns*/
  /* insignificant */
  width: 50%;
}

div#column-container div {
  background-color: yellow;

  /* set shadow for yellow elements */
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 15px #000;

  /* Make sure that yellow div is not split between columns */
  display: inline-block;

  /* the rest - not significant */
  width: 46%;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 2%;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an idea of workaround, but it is not equivalent - when boxes are rendered as a standard floats, not columns, the order is different: http://jsfiddle.net/buli_pl/bbA5q/

Comment: I think that a better option (but still a workaround) is to over-size the column element's width and also add side margins to your shadow-casting elements. However, this is unfortunately the best solution without resorting to something other than columns, which offers _absolutely_ no column-to-shadow overlap (because it will visibly clip/crop your shadows if you overlap at all). :( Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issues with a 3 column layout. Chrome cut the box-shadow but only on top in column 2 and 3...

box-shadow cut

[image]

Margin Workaround:

```
.item {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #000;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15px; /* same as box-shadow blur */     
  width: 100%;
}
.container{
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 30px;
  margin-top: -15px;/* negative value same as box-shadow blur & item margin-top */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div#column-container {   
    /* Set 2 columns*/
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    display: block;

     /* insignificant */
    width: 50%;
}

div#column-container div {
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 5%;

    /* set shadow for yellow elements */
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 15px #000;
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 15px #000;

    /* Make sure that yellow div is not split between columns */
    display: block;

    /* the rest - not significant */
    height: 70px;
}
```

This will give you almost similar look.

And the [Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/FYGat/).

**P.S.Alter the margin and width values by yourself to make the boxes closer as per your requirement.**

Comment: As in other comments, please note that boxes are not numbered the same when using floating boxes! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a related bug filed with chromium. Basically, it seems that chrome just isn't that good at rendering the css `columns` properties. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=467196

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround is to surround your boxes in larger transparent divs that leave enough room for the shadow. This solves both of the problems.

```
<div id="column-container">
  <div class="outer"><div>box 1</div></div>
  <div class="outer"><div>box 2</div></div>
  <div class="outer"><div>box 3</div></div>
  <div class="outer"><div>box 4</div></div>
  <div class="outer"><div>box 5</div></div>
  <div class="outer"><div>box 6</div></div>
</div>
```

```
div#column-container {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}

div#column-container div {
  background-color: yellow;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  break-inside: avoid;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 20px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.box {
  break-inside: avoid;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 2rem;
}
.item {
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  break-inside: avoid;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Comment: Please provide some context to your answer.