# CSS column snipping

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

As you can see in the image at the bottom, the column is getting snipped.

http://jsfiddle.net/eecvpru5/2/

Here is my code:

```
.dress-gallery {
    position: relative;
    background: #FEFEFE;
    border: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
    margin-top: 1em;

    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Firefox */
    column-break-inside: avoid; /* IE 10+ */

    .price {
        font-size: 0.8em;
        padding-left: 0.5em;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #333;
    }

    .retailer {
        font-size: 0.8em;
        margin: 0.15em 0.5em;
        clear: both;
    }

    .list-count {
        padding-left: 0.5em;
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }

    .list-name {
        font-size: 0.8em;
        margin: 0.15em 0.5em;
        clear: both;
    }
}

.dress-gallery:hover .image-overlay {
    display: block;
}

.image-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dress-gallery" style="-webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;">
    <a href="#">        
        <img src="image.png" />
    </a>
    <div class="image-overlay">
        <div class="overlay-buttons">
            <a href="#">View</a>
            <a href="#">Buy</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <span class="price">$127.00 USD</span>
    <span class="retailer pull-right">Revolve Clothing</span>
</div>
```

I have found a solution to change the .dress-gallery to display as an inline-block. But since the image-overlay must need the position of dress-gallery to be relative, it won't position correctly.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but don't understand what you are referring to with "the column is getting snipped". Can you clarify?

Comment: @JoeConlin As you can see the bottom of the image is clipped off and sent over to the beginning of the next column.

Comment: Ahh, I get it now. Unfortunately, hard to help without seeing the html to see exactly what is getting snipped. Can you post a Fiddle or provide a link to where this is happening. Should be an easy fix once seen.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I have posted the html.

Comment: please provide a fiddle or a pen

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eecvpru5/2/

Comment: Seems to be an issue with WebKit/Blink, `(-webkit-)column-count` and children having `box-shadow` applied to them. You can find a lot of problems related to this ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881923/box-shadow-trimmed-in-css-columns-in-chrome), [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=269061), [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129178) etc.). Try adding `margin: 2px` to `.dress-gallery`. Though using this relatively new stuff will give you more head-aches than it may solve problem. Also looks borked in Firefox.

Comment: Are you using some kind of css preprocessors (Sass/Less) ?

Comment: @maryisdead The margin seemed to do nothing.

Comment: @Konrud, Yes I am using SASS.

Comment: @Adherence have you tried to reduce column count ?

Comment: @Konrud The column count didn't change it either. The answer posted by Phlume is the solution I have used.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the column-gap and moving to a flexbox model:

http://jsfiddle.net/eecvpru5/4/

css

```
#column-gallery {
padding: 1em 2em;
background-color: #efefef;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
-webkit-align-content: flex-start;
-ms-flex-line-pack: start;
align-content: flex-start;
-webkit-align-items: flex-start;
-ms-flex-align: start;
align-items: flex-start;
outline: none;
```

I used the referenced fiddle from @maryisdead, and that led me here: 
[Box-shadow trimmed in CSS columns in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881923/box-shadow-trimmed-in-css-columns-in-chrome)

From that questions accepted answer, I used their fiddle:
 
http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/KxYRc/19/

When I copied it into yours on FF it seemed to work. You'll still have to adjust for your specific needs and image size, but the wrap is now gone.

Comment: It may get rid of the snipping but it doesn't put it into columns.